# How to get item after selected item in Wpf DataGrid based on criteria?

Tags: c#, wpf, datagrid

I have a data grid from which I can delete items. Deleting an item means that it is not visible on the dataGrid anymore, but it is still in DataSource.

How can I set the item (that will be visible in the list after I remove the currently selected item) as selected?

I need to get the object itself because I have to check some extra criteria, but the only way I can think of is some nasty for loops.

```
private void OnTakeOneClick(object sender, RoutedEventArgs e)
{
    var tableSelectedItem = (PartialPaymentDTO)this.TableDataGrid.SelectedItem;
    // var nextItemInGrid = ???

    Model.TakeOrderItemsFromTable(tableSelectedItem);

    if(tableSelectedItem.QuantityOnTable != 0)
    {
        this.TableDataGrid.SelectedItem = tableSelectedItem;
    }
    else
    {
        // select next item in data grid that based on some extra criteria
    }
}
```

Edit: Getting the whole list of items after selected item would be really helpful too.

**Please notice** that I don't remove items from my data source. Instead I hide them in grid based on criteria.

WPF:

```
<DataGrid ItemsSource="{Binding TableItems}" Name="TableDataGrid"  AutoGenerateColumns="False" 
          SelectionChanged ="OnTableDataGridSelected" HeadersVisibility="Column" BorderThickness="0"  SelectionMode="Single">
    <DataGrid.ItemContainerStyle>
        <Style TargetType="DataGridRow">
            <Style.Triggers>
                <DataTrigger Binding="{Binding QuantityOnTable}"  Value="0">
                    <Setter Property="Visibility" Value="Collapsed"/>
                </DataTrigger>
            </Style.Triggers>
        </Style>
    </DataGrid.ItemContainerStyle>
    <DataGrid.Columns>
        <DataGridTextColumn Header="Artikl" Binding="{Binding OrderItemName}" IsReadOnly="True" Width="*">
            <DataGridTextColumn.ElementStyle>
                <Style TargetType="{x:Type TextBlock}">
                    <Setter Property="TextAlignment" Value="Left"/>
                    <Setter Property="Padding" Value="0,6"/>
                    <Setter Property="TextWrapping" Value="NoWrap"/>
                </Style>
            </DataGridTextColumn.ElementStyle>
        </DataGridTextColumn>
    </DataGrid.Columns>
</DataGrid>
```

Comment: Are you using data binding to populate the data grid and set the current selected item?  If so we could use the xaml.  Otherwise, why not use .IndexOf() on the current items before delete the select that index after delete?

Comment: Yes I am using data binding, but `AutoGenerateColumns="False" `

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As there are many items in the list, looping through all items on every removal was not an option.

In the end this is how I determined the next item that needs to be selected

```
private void OnTakeOneClick(object sender, RoutedEventArgs e)
{
    var tableSelectedItem = (PartialPaymentDTO)this.TableDataGrid.SelectedItem;
    Model.TakeOrderItemsFromTable(tableSelectedItem);

    if(tableSelectedItem.QuantityOnTable != 0)
    {
        this.TableDataGrid.SelectedItem = tableSelectedItem;
    }
    else
    {
        int currentSelectedItemIndex = this.TableDataGrid.Items.IndexOf(tableSelectedItem);
        // Skip items before currently selected items
        var tableDataGridItemsAfterSelected = this.TableDataGrid.Items.OfType<PartialPaymentDTO>().Skip(currentSelectedItemIndex);
        foreach (var item in tableDataGridItemsAfterSelected)
        {
            if (item.QuantityOnTable != 0) // Criteria check
            {
                this.TableDataGrid.SelectedItem = item;
                break;
            }
        }
    }
}
```

Answer (score 1):

Try this if you want to select the item that follows `tableSelectedItem` in the `Items` collection of the `DataGrid`:

```
var tableSelectedItem = (PartialPaymentDTO)this.TableDataGrid.SelectedItem;
int indexOfSelectedItem = this.TableDataGrid.Items.IndexOf(tableSelectedItem);
int indexOfNextItem = indexOfSelectedItem + 1;
if (this.TableDataGrid.Items.Count > indexOfNextItem)
    this.TableDataGrid.SelectedItem = this.TableDataGrid.Items[indexOfNextItem];
```

Comment: Thank you, it is not the answer i've been looking for but it lead me to the answer.

Comment: The answer you have posted uses the IndexOf method as I suggested so what's the difference? And IndexOf and OfType do certainly use a loop under the hood...

Comment: Object that is next in the list doesn't have to fulfill the criteria to be the next selected item. So taking the index + 1 item was not enough.
Again, thank you for your answer, it helped me to solve my problem but it was not the solution for my question.

Comment: It was certainly the answer to your original question about how to get the index of the next item in the collection...